# Downloading Pradhan Mantri Gram Sadak Yojana (PMGSY) GIS data?

Tags: geospatial, india

I am trying to download road data from the PMGSY/GRRIS website (http://www.pmgsy-grris.nic.in/). While the in-site visualizations are helpful, I wanted to know if there was a way to access the raw data used to create these maps. My understanding is that it is all stored on a SQL server, but I am not sure if this is accessible to the public.